How to receive CreationTimestamp value with Hibernate on update?
I hope I'm not missing any obvious parts from the documentation, but is it possible for me to obtain the value of the @CreationTimestamp field during the update? (without an additional request)
For example the entity has 2 fields:
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp created;

@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp updated;

When you create an entity having both of the fields as null by the CrudRepository.save() it returns a response with new timestamps.
When you update an existing entity with the same method having both fields as null, the response has a new value for the updated field while the created is null.
Is it possible to obtain the persisted value for the created field during the same request?

Currently I haven't found anything better than to apply the entityManager.refresh(obj) when the save(obj) is done. I'm not sure if it's the best way but it works.
